# Foreach in a foreach and filtering through both of them

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I am trying show related posts through posts linked through a category in wordpress but I am having trouble filtering the results.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
     $current_post = $post->ID;
         $i = 0;
         $categories = get_the_category();
         foreach ($categories as $category) {            
            $posts = get_posts('numberposts=4&category='. $category->term_id . '&exclude=' . $post->ID);
                foreach($posts as $post) { 
                                     // DO BASIC ECHO POST CONTENT STUFF

                     $i++;
                     if ($i == 3) break;
                         }
           } 


wp_reset_query();
```

The problem with my code is that when a post is in 3 categories (even if that isn't good web practise) this loop echo's 12 posts (4 posts per category) and if a different article is in the same 3 categories, it is shown 3 times (duplicated). I want to show MAX 4 posts, and have no duplicates.

I thought the $i == 3 break; would make it stop after the first 'global' 4 results. But it doesn't? and how can I make it so there are no duplicate results in the results?

Comment: can't the function `get_posts()` do any filtering using `GROUP BY` on the sql-side?

Comment: You break will only stop the posts loop. If you want to stop the twice loop, try using `if ($i == 3) break 2;`

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what you want the output to be.  Perhaps you could give an example.

Comment: increment `$i` outside of the `foreach($posts as $post) {}` loop

Comment: Thanks guys, but spin0us got it this time! I needed to break the category foreach too and I didn't realise that! thanks :) How can I mark this as solved and has a correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$current_post = $post->ID;
         $i = 0;
         $categories = get_the_category();
         foreach ($categories as $category) {            
            $posts = get_posts('numberposts=4&category='. $category->term_id . '&exclude=' . $post->ID);
                foreach($posts as $post) { 
                                     // DO BASIC ECHO POST CONTENT STUFF

                     $i++;
                     if ($i == 3) break 2;
                         }
           }
```

wp_reset_query();

Answer (score 1):

You can create array of shown posts and then check if post not in this array show it.

```
$show_array = array();

// ...

foreach($posts as $post) { 
   if (!in_array($post['id'], $show_array)) {
       // show post
       $show_array[] = $post['id'];
   }
}
```